# StackOverFlow Exception: Could you help me about this issue?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow, builder

[image]

I designed a class implementing the Builder design pattern. But creating that class using its builder, it throws System Exception that is StackOverFlow Exception. I know its builder is recursive but I only call three times its building chain. What throwing I really don't understand and it doesn't come to me logically. Below is my class that involves its own builder.

```
SnirgeeDosya sn = new SnirgeeDosya.SnirgeeDosyaBuilder()
            .setDosyaId(0)
            .setDosyaAdi("Dosya1")
            .setUserId(1214)
            .setDBFactory(new DatabaseFactory()).build();




public class SnirgeeDosya:ISnirgeeDosyaOracleCommands
  {

    public int dosyaId { set { dosyaId = value; } get { return dosyaId; } }
    public int userId { set { userId = value; } get { return userId; } }
    public DateTime baslangicZaman { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
    public String dosyaAdi { set { dosyaAdi = value; } get { return dosyaAdi; } }
    private SnirgeeOracleDBWorker oracleDbWorker{ set { oracleDbWorker = value; } get { return oracleDbWorker; } } 


    /// <summary>
    /// SnirgeeDosya olusturması sırasında kullanılır. ilgili parametreler girildikten sonra build edilip SnirgeeDosya elde edilir. Kullanım şekli aşağıdaki gibidir.
    /// SnirgeeDosya sn = new SnirgeeDosya.SnirgeeDosyaBuilder().setDosyaAdi("Dosya1").setUserId(1214).setDBFactory(new DatabaseFactory()).build();

    /// </summary>
    public  class SnirgeeDosyaBuilder
    {
      public int dosyaId { set { dosyaId = value; } get { return dosyaId; } }
      public int userId { set { userId = value; } get { return userId; } }
      public String dosyaAdi { set { dosyaAdi = value; } get { return dosyaAdi; } }
      public SnirgeeOracleDBWorker oracleDbWorker { set { oracleDbWorker = value; } get { return oracleDbWorker; } } 

      /// <summary>
      /// Dosya Builder içerinde dosya adının belirlenmesi.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="dosyaadi"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public SnirgeeDosyaBuilder setDosyaAdi(String dosyaadi)
      {
        this.dosyaAdi = dosyaadi;
        return this;
      }
      /// <summary>
      /// Dosya Builder içerinde SnirgeeDosyasının kime ait olduğunu belirten metotdur.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="userid"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public SnirgeeDosyaBuilder setUserId(int userid)
      {
        this.userId = userid;
        return this;
      }
      /// <summary>
      /// Dosya Builder içerinde SnirgeeDosyasının kime ait olduğunu belirten metotdur.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="userid"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public SnirgeeDosyaBuilder setDosyaId(int dosyaId)
      {
        this.dosyaId = dosyaId;
        return this;
      }
      /// <summary>
      /// Snirgee Dosyasının içerisine Veritabanı işlemleri yapan classın eklenmesi. 
      /// Elementlerin yazılması ve okunması sırasında bu class içerisinde kullanılacaktır.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="db"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public SnirgeeDosyaBuilder setDBFactory(DatabaseFactory db)
      {
        this.oracleDbWorker = new SnirgeeOracleDBWorker(db);
        return this;
      }
      /// <summary>
      /// dosyaAdı, kullanıcıId ve Veritabanı işlerini yapacak DatabaseFactory parametreleri atandıktan sonra Snirgee Dosyasını oluşturan methodtur.
      /// Henüz veritabanı SnirgeeDosya tablosuna herhangi bir kayıt atanmaz.
      /// </summary>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public SnirgeeDosya build()
      {
        return new SnirgeeDosya(this);
      }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// SnirgeeDosya'sını oluşturan SnirgeeDosyaBuilder classı build metodu içerisinde kullanılır.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="formBuilder"></param>
    private SnirgeeDosya(SnirgeeDosyaBuilder formBuilder)
    {
      this.dosyaId = formBuilder.dosyaId;
      this.userId = formBuilder.userId;
      this.dosyaAdi = formBuilder.dosyaAdi;
      this.oracleDbWorker = formBuilder.oracleDbWorker;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Infinite loop in getter/setter c#](//stackoverflow.com/a/16694128)

Answer (score 1):

Common mistake. Your property is calling itself in the getter/setter.  So when you set `dosyaId`, it sets `dosyaId`, which sets `dosyaId`, which sets `dosyaId`, which... until the call stack is full and you get a `StackOverflowException`.

Change

```
public int dosyaId { set { dosyaId = value; } get { return dosyaId; } }
```

to

```
public int dosyaId { set; get; }
```

And the same for the other properties. I see no need for you to have a backing field based on what you've posted. In fact, I see no need for the `set...` methods either - you can just set the properties directly.

Comment: ı really thank you.  it seems to fix my problem your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's an infinite loop - in the property, you're setting the property, which calls the property setter, which sets the property, etc. until the exception.

Either create a member variable (with a different name, this is known as a backing field) that the property sets and gets, or, since these are very simple properties, make them auto-implemented:

```
public int dosyaId { get; set; }
```

Comment: ı appreciated you. it solves my problem.